# My configuration pom.xml has skipped test. But now I want to run test once with command line. How is the command?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, api, maven

My configuration pom.xml has skipped test as true for maven-surefire-plugin as below. I generally skip these test since they are unstale.

```
 <build> 
    <plugins> 
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.8</version> 
        <configuration> 
          <skipTests>true</skipTests> 
        </configuration> 
      </plugin> 
    </plugins> 
  </build>
```

But now I want to run test once with command line to try to see the test results. I think mvn command line should can be -DvarNewValue to override the var old value configurated in pom.xml as ANT.
So I try "mvn test -DskipTests=false". But the test still been skipped.

```
D:\GIT_Work\iVIEW8.5\oss\xml\xmlservice\api>mvn test -DskipTests=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xmlservice-api 8.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ xmlservice-api ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ xmlservice-api ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- native2ascii-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:native2ascii (native2ascii) @ xmlservice-api ---
[INFO] Includes: [*.properties]
[INFO] Excludes: []
[INFO] Processing D:\GIT_Work\iVIEW8.5\oss\xml\xmlservice\api\target\classes\xmlservicebiz.properties
[INFO] Processing D:\GIT_Work\iVIEW8.5\oss\xml\xmlservice\api\target\classes\xmlservicebiz_zh_CN.properties
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ xmlservice-api ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ xmlservice-api ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (default-test) @ xmlservice-api ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.939s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 18 17:47:24 CST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/371M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How is the correct command line to run the test configrated as skipping in pom.xml one time to try?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your pom is configured to skip tests but you want to run them? Why not configuring the pom not to skip tests?

Comment: I generally skip these test since they are unstale while develping and debugging phase. But now I want to run test once with command line to try to see the test results after much develping and debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the behavior of the plugin from command line, you have to define a property:

```
<properties>
  <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>
```

and use it in plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Source:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html